# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeQuery() must be an instance of MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference,

Tags: php, mongodb

Mongo db version 2.6 
Php mongodb extension version 1.1.5

```
$m= new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
$db = $m->mydb;
$collection = $db->mycollection;
$result = $collection->find();
```

It produce the error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeQuery() must be an instance of MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference
```

But the same code is work fine in 
Mongo version 3.4
php extension 1.5.1

Then why it is not work in my configuration

Comment: Because they're wildely different versions and stuff changes, probably.